# How to access to interface of a pointered function

Tags: go, reflection

For the validator I have the following interface

```
type validatorInterface interface {
    IsValid() error
}

func customValidation(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    field := fl.Field().Interface()
    validatorObject, ok := field.(validatorInterface)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    err := validatorObject.IsValid()
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

It work perfect if the field to validate has the function implemented without pointer. Like that:

```
func (s s) IsValid()
```

but the conversion to the interface fails if it is implemented like that

```
func (s *s) IsValid()
```

How can I improve the customValidation to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally I found and answer. I remember that the encoding/json library do that so I looked at it and I found

```
    // If v is a named type and is addressable,
    // start with its address, so that if the type has pointer methods,
    // we find them.
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Pointer && v.Type().Name() != "" && v.CanAddr() {
        haveAddr = true
        v = v.Addr()
    }
```

I implemented that in that way and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is implemented by reference, you need that `fl.Field().Interface()` will return an reference.

https://go.dev/play/p/iYTibDNrH5E

Well, it's also more accurate, since if the method is by reference, you probably want to pass a reference to the object.